# Spring redirect view is not working

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I am using **Spring Controllers** to show my jsp views and Spring security.

In security context, **all users can access to /login** (login.jsp) but **only authenticated users can access to /home** (home.jsp).

When i remove the session id from browser cookies, the next request in the app should redirect to login page.

My method to show login page in controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login","/login.do"})
public ModelAndView showLoginForm() {

    String username = getUsername();
    if(!username.equals("anonymousUser")){
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home"); 
    }
   return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

My url is on /home but when i try to redirect to login using this function   **return new ModelAndView("login")** the browsers stay with the same url.

My spring security config

```
<http  entry-point-ref="loginEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
    <session-management
        session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.do" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup/createuser" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/changepassword/changefirstpassword" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/recoverpassword/recoverPasswordRequest" access="permitAll" />  
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied.do" />
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="domainFormLoginFilter" />
    <logout success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler" />
</http>
```

Why my browser doesnt redirect to login page? tks

Comment: Why are you hacking things together yourself? Spring Security already does that for you.... Also you aren't redirecting only forwarding...

Comment: i dont have controllers to returns my views?

Answer (score 1):

First remove your controller and add the following to your security configuration.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
```

Work with the framework not against or around it...

Comment: i dont have controllers to returns my views?

Comment: i read many examples and all of them have controllers to return views

Comment: If i dont have a controller to return my view, when you enter /login the request is not found. i have spring security book and all the views have a controller to return the view name

Comment: Trust me you don't... Also it beats the purpose of having to do security checks yourself if you have Spring Security doesn't it... Add your configuration to your question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: can you show me an example with controllers to mapping views?

Comment: No as you don't need them, they only add complexity and you gain nothing. You don't need it to render your login page. Just configure the `<sec:form-login />` correctly.

Comment: i am my spring security config. is not basic. i am not using form-login.

Comment: Well you are using a form to login, just configure the filter you are using correctly. As mentioned you don't need a controller and I wouldn't suggest adding one, is pretty much useless and adds only stuff to your application that you don't need. But that is IMHO... If you really want, use a view controller but don't add controllers because you need simple name to JSP translation.

Comment: ok my friend. i will review my code and update it to remove controllers. thanks for your help!